# pandas cut by the mount column

Tags: pandas, numpy

A pandas dataframe(x) with two columns: sum and value. sum is the count of records has the same value. For example:

```
sum value
2     3
4    1
```

means 2 records has value 3 and 4 records has value 1
And what I want to do is: sort by value and then cut [1,1,1,1,3,3] into 3 parts: [1,1], [1,1], [3,3]

How to cut the value into 3 parts and Each part has an equal number of records?

pandas.cut can't take sum column into consideration

Comment: So in effect you want to split `[3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]` into three? What exactly are the rules for doing that?

Comment: @JonClements Yes, I added rules in my question

Comment: Right... so how is the ordering of the split decided... why isn't it `[[3, 3], [1, 1], [1,1]]` or other combinations?

Comment: sort by value column @JonClements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) with double [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
sumall = df['sum'].sum()
df = df.sort_values(by='value')
df['sum_sum'] = df['sum'].cumsum()
df['tag'] = np.where(df['sum_sum'] < sumall / 3, 0, 
            np.where(df['sum_sum'] < 2 * sumall / 3, 1, 2) )

print (df)
   sum  value  sum_sum  tag
1    4      1        4    2
0    2      3        6    2
```

Comment: If the sum is too large to do record repeat?

Comment: Can you explain more? Memory problem ?

Comment: I try modify your function, please check if works well.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me. but ugly:

```
sum = df['sum'].sum()
def func(x):
    if x < sum/3:
        return 0
    elif x < 2 * sum/3:
        return 1
    return 2
df = df.sort_values(by='value')
df['sum_sum'] = np.cumsum(df['sum'].values)
df['tag'] = df['sum_sum'].apply(func)
```